# Generate histogram from regex matches

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sorry if this is an obvious question. I'm quite new to SQL and couldn't manage to adapt other examples out there to my needs.

I have a table (Postgres 9.3) defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE scripts (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
content TEXT NOT NULL);
```

The content column contains the content of various scripts. I'm interested in counting how many times distinct function calls occur in these scripts.

I've managed to construct a query that runs a regex over the contents, and pulls out all the function calls (as funcs)

```
SELECT id, name, regexp_matches(LOWER(content), '(\w+\.\w+)\(', 'g') AS funcs
FROM scripts
GROUP BY id, name, funcs;
```

The output looks something like

```
1, myscript, {class.m1}<br>
2, otherscript, {class_b.method4}<br>
2, otherscript, {class.m1}<br>
3, last_script, {classname.method2}<br>
3, last_script, {class.m1}<br>
3, last_script, {class_b.method4}<br>
```

I would really like to turn this into a table that shows a tally of each distinct function. Something like

```
class.m1, 3
class_b.method4, 2
classname.method2, 1
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT funcs) FROM (
    SELECT tsr_id, name, regexp_matches(LOWER(content), '(\w+\.\w+)\(', 'g') AS funcs
        FROM tsr_conf.rules
        GROUP BY tsr_id, name, funcs
) x
```

But unfortunately it just gives me the total count of distinct functions. Any advice on how to count the occurances of each distinct function would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what your first query returns, a `group by` should do what you want:

```
SELECT funcs, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT tsr_id, name, regexp_matches(LOWER(content), '(\w+\.\w+)\(', 'g') AS funcs
      FROM tsr_conf.rules
      GROUP BY tsr_id, name, funcs
     ) x
GROUP BY funcs;
```

You could actually write this more simply as:

```
SELECT regexp_matches(LOWER(content), '(\w+\.\w+)\(', 'g') AS funcs, COUNT(DISTINCT tsr_id, name)
FROM tsr_conf.rules
GROUP BY funcs;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon. Many thanks for your answer! The first query you gave works perfectly. 

Thanks again!